# How to create custom php script to display products special price in magento 2?

Tags: php, magento-2.1.3

Can you help me on how to create a php script to display all products with special price including it's sku.

Comment: Write more about it.

Comment: Hi Sohel, I'd like to display only the products with special price with a value of 0 only and display also it's SKU so that I can track them down. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use these Code for your requirement

```
<?php
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('app/bootstrap.php');

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager
    ->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$productcollection = $productCollectionFactory->create()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->load();
                    
foreach ($productcollection as $product) {
    if ($product->getSpecialPrice() == 0) {
        echo $product->getId()."<br/>";
        echo $product->getSku()."<br/>";
    }       
}
```

Comment: Hi Pranay k, Thanks for this code. I'll try this and let you know if it worked. Thanks again

Comment: This code works better in my end. Thanks again

Comment: your Welcome @MazeStricks

Answer (score 1):

Please create a test.php file at your magento2 root directory

Inser below code into `test.php`

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$params = $_SERVER; 
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$productCollection = $obj->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$collection = $productCollection->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->load();

foreach ($collection as $product){

     echo 'SKU:  '.$product->getSku().'<br>';   
     echo 'Name:  '.$product->getName().'<br>';
     echo 'Price:    '.$product->getPrice().'<br>';
     echo 'Special price:    '.$product->getSpecialPrice().'<br>';
     echo '----------------------------<br>';       

}
```

now run URL: like  : http://yourdomain/test.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Mage::app();
$products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();
$fp = fopen('getId.csv', 'w');
$csvHeader = array("id","sku","images");
fputcsv($fp, $csvHeader, ",");
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $id = $product->getId();
    $sku = $product->getSku();
    $gallery_images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
    $items = array();
    foreach($gallery_images as $g_image) {
        $items[] = $g_image['url'];
    }
    fputcsv($fp, array($id,$sku,implode(',', $items)), ",");
}
fclose($fp);
```